# AsyncTask and RecyclerView Don't Display the Contents Obtained from JSON on the Internet

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I'm making a simple program where I can get a content from JSON in this url

> https://www.haliminfo.com/feeds/posts/summary/?max-results=10&start-index=1&alt=json

and make it a list Using RecyclerView on Android.

I have made several necessary components such as Model, Adapter, Post Row Item and HttpHandler

when I try RecyclerView with a method like this it works.

```
private void addData () {
    postsArrayList = new ArrayList <> ();
    postsArrayList.add (new Posts ("TITLE", "SUMMARY"));
}
```

but when I apply the method below nothing appears in the activity

```
private class getContent extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        @ Override
        protected Void doInBackground (Void ... voids) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler ();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall (URL_FIX);

            if (jsonStr! = null) {

                try {

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject (jsonStr);

                    JSONObject feed = jsonObj.getJSONObject ("feed");
                    JSONArray entry = feed.getJSONArray ("entry");

                    Posts postsModel = new Posts ();

                    for (int i = 0; i <entry.length (); i ++) {

                        postsModel.setTitle (entry.getJSONObject (i) .getJSONObject ("title"). getString ("$ t"));
                        postsModel.setSummary (entry.getJSONObject (i) .getJSONObject ("summary"). getString ("$ t"));

                        postsArrayList.add (postsModel);

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e ("RESPONSE", "Json parsing error:" + e.getMessage ());
                    runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {
                        @ Override
                        public void run () {
                            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (),
                                    "Json parsing error:" + e.getMessage (),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show ();
                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                Log.e ("RESPONSE", "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread (new Runnable () {
                    @ Override
                    public void run () {
                        Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show ();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

this is a full file of some important files in my project

> **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.badjing.bloggercoba.activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.badjing.bloggercoba.R;
import com.badjing.bloggercoba.adapter.PostRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.badjing.bloggercoba.config.Config;
import com.badjing.bloggercoba.handler.HttpHandler;
import com.badjing.bloggercoba.model.Posts;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private PostRecyclerViewAdapter postAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Posts> postsArrayList;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private Config config = new Config();
    String URL_FIX = Config.BLOG_URL + Config.BLOG_URL_MAX_RESULT + Config.MAX_RESULT + config.BLOG_URL_START_INDEX + config.START_INDEX + config.BLOG_URL_ALT_TYPE;;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        postsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        new getContent().execute();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_recycle_view);
        postAdapter = new PostRecyclerViewAdapter(postsArrayList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);


    }

//    private void addData() {
//
//        postsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
//        postsArrayList.add(new Posts("JUDUL", "SUMMARY"));
//
//    }

    private class getContent extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

//        @Override
//        protected void onPreExecute() {
//            super.onPreExecute();
//            // Showing progress dialog
//            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
//            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
//            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
//            pDialog.show();
//        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URL_FIX);

            if (jsonStr != null) {

                try{

                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    JSONObject feed = jsonObj.getJSONObject("feed");
                    JSONArray entry = feed.getJSONArray("entry");

                    Posts postsModel = new Posts();



                    for (int i = 0; i < entry.length(); i++) {

                        postsModel.setTitle(entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("title").getString("$t"));
                        postsModel.setSummary(entry.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("summary").getString("$t"));

                        postsArrayList.add(postsModel);

                    }

                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("RESPONSE", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            } else {
                Log.e("RESPONSE", "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

    private void urlBuilder() {
        URL_FIX = Config.BLOG_URL + Config.BLOG_URL_MAX_RESULT + 10 + config.BLOG_URL_START_INDEX + 1 + config.BLOG_URL_ALT_TYPE;
    }
}
```

> **Post.java** (post model)

```
package com.badjing.bloggercoba.model;

public class Posts {
    String title;
    String summary;

    public Posts() {
    }


    public Posts(String title, String summary) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }
}
```

> **PostRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.badjing.bloggercoba.adapter;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.badjing.bloggercoba.R;
import com.badjing.bloggercoba.model.Posts;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PostRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Posts> postsList;

    public PostRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Posts> postsArrayList) {
        this.postsList = postsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.post_row_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.blog_post_title.setText(postsList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.blog_post_sumary.setText(postsList.get(position).getSummary());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (postsList!= null) ? postsList.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView blog_post_title, blog_post_sumary, blog_post_author;
        ImageView img_thumbnail;


        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            blog_post_title     = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_post_title);
            blog_post_sumary    = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_post_sumary);
//            blog_post_author    = itemView.findViewById(R.id.blog_post_author);
//            img_thumbnail       = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_thumbnail);

        }
    }

}
```

> **post_row_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/post_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/loading_shape"></ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_post_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blog post title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_post_sumary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="blog post summary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blog_post_author"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="~ author"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: GetContent class is async call so it may take some time to get API result. So when you get `postsArrayList` completely that is after `for loop` inside  GetContent class add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: After adding one or more items to *postsArrayList* it is necessary to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the RecyclerView.Adapter. You could override `onPostExecute()` in the AsyncTask to do so since this method will be executed on the UI thread

Comment: One more thing: in `doInBackground()` you have just one instance *postsModel* of `Posts` Inside the loop, you keep changing it and add it repeatedly to the list. But since all items of the list point to the same instance, they all will have the same values. **TL;DR** you need to create a new instance of `Posts` for each list item

Comment: thanks bro for your help, its work